# What was the scene in King's Cross all about?

Tags: harry-potter

After being cursed by Voldemort for the second time, Harry spiritually goes to King's Cross and talks to Dumbledore. Is it like a coming back to life scene or is it caused by the dying Horcrux (or rather Voldemot's soul piece) inside him?

Comment: It's a construct of his imagination. Presumably because he is in a semi coma / unconscious?

Comment: HUH? How's that a duplicate???

Answer (score 14):

It's unlikely that it's *caused* by the "Horcrux" (remember that Harry wasn't actually a Horcrux in the first place, so I assume you meant to say "Voldemort's soul piece"), but there's no direct evidence either way. Most of what JKR says seems to point to it being a limbo state where Harry has to choose between moving on to death, and returning to life:

In canon:

- **Books**:

  According to Dumbledore, it's uncertain:

  > “Tell me one last thing,” said Harry. “Is this real? Or has this
  >   been happening inside my head?”
  >   Dumbledore beamed at him, and his voice sounded loud and strong in Harry’s ears even though the bright white mist was descending again, obscuring his figure.
  >   “**Of course it is happening inside your head, Harry, but why on earth should that mean that it is not real**?”
  >
  > “Well, where do you think we are?” asked Harry, a little defensively.
  >   “My dear boy, I have no idea. This is, as they say, **your party**.”
- **JKR Interviews**:

  Unknown, on purpose.

  > **Elisabeth**: In the chapter of kings cross, are they behind the veil or in some world between the real world and the veil?
  >   **J.K. Rowling**: You can make up your own mind on this, but I think that Harry entered a kind of limbo between life and death.
  >   (*[J.K. Rowling and the Live Chat, Bloomsbury.com](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0730-bloomsbury-chat.html), July 30, 2007 (2.00-3.00pm BST).*)
  >
  > **Katie B:** Why was kings cross the place harry went to when he died
  >   **J.K. Rowling:** For many reasons. The name works rather well, and it has been established in the books as the gateway between two worlds, **and Harry would associate it with moving on between two worlds** (**don't forget that it is Harry's image we see**, not necessarily what is really there).
- **Pottermore**:

  Unknown as of yet as that point in the timeline isn't yet on Pottermore