# Why King's Cross?

Tags: harry-potter

When Voldemort does the Avada kadavra on Harry in the forest, Harry goes into some kind of passing between worlds, that looks to him like King's Cross Station. So why does Harry see himself there? What is the significance of that place? Theoretically, would anyone who's half-dead see himself in King's Cross?
In a closer look at DH chapter 35 I have some more questions-

> "It looks," he said slowly, "like King's Cross station. Except a lot cleaner and empty, and there are no trains as far as I can see."
> "King's Cross Station!" Dumbledore was chuckling immoderately. "Good gracious, really?"

Why does Dumbledore seem surprised? And why is it important that the station is empty?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What was the scene in King's Cross all about?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94126/what-was-the-scene-in-kings-cross-all-about) - the earlier question covers this one as well, and the answer provides a JKR interview where she was asked _"Why was kings cross the place harry went to when he died"_

Comment: Quite possibly, and this is pure conjecture, Harry sees this as a place where two worlds meet - including the Muggle world and the magical world.

Comment: It's part dream, and dreams are mental fruit salad that the right side if your brain whips up while the left side is out of action.